# UPDATE query overflowed data type on unwanted row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table, say, `CREATE TABLE #t(col1 int)`. Then, `INSERT INTO #t VALUES(1)`.

Now I try to make an fake int overflow by both two ways:

```
UPDATE #t
SET col1 = 999999*999999
WHERE col1 = 2

UPDATE #t
SET col1 = 999999*999999
WHERE 1 = 2
```

While neither query will actually update any rows, the first query raises int overflow error, but second not.

Things get tricky when problem is more likely to production event, say, a table have some value columns and a category column. Executing the query:

```
UPDATE table
SET column = <a computation from other columns>
WHERE category = <category>
```

Suppose some data that are not in this category will get overflow by the computation, the query will, or will not raise error during execution, probably depend on the execution plan SQL server was chosen.

But I was just curious that why `SELECT` value **might** get computed out before the 'WHERE' operates first, doesn't makes sense to the common execution order of a common SQL query?? and if such problem occurs, how can we circumvent it?

Comment: It is not that simple. Before executing a query, there is a query optimizer, wich take care about multiple circunstances: table size, indexes, foreign keys... So the same query could be executed with different order in different tables. Yo could check some theory here: http://infolab.stanford.edu/~hyunjung/cs346/ioannidis.pdf or simply look for query optimizer on google :)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the second query fails before the query plan reaches the value to be used in the `SET` clause.  That is, the `WHERE` clause is evaluated first, and, since it fails, the query never progresses to reach the stack overflow error.

In practice, in a production setting, the query in question would presumably have a `WHERE` clause which would be true at least some of the time.  So, you would still see the stack overflow error in your logs, at least occasionally.